# Multiple Linear Regression problems in R with "ldpy"

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to calculate multiple linear regression with R and I would like to obtain the results in a dataframe. I have to use filters because I need to calculate regression to differents countries:

```
## No controls. ("unadjusted" pay gap.)
model1 <- dlply(data, 'Pais', function(df) 
lm(log_total ~ male, data = df)
## Apply coef to each model and return a data frame 
df1 <- ldply(model1, coef)
model2 <- dlply(data, 'Pais', function(df)  
lm(log_total ~ male + age_bin, data = df))
df2 <- ldply(model2, coef)
### Adding all controls. ("adjusted" pay gap.)
model3 <- dlply(data, 'Pais', function(df) 
lm(log_total ~ male + + age_bin + dept + seniority + jobTitle, data = df))
df3 <- ldply(model3, coef)
```

I have problems in model 3 because I do not obtain df3 and I do not know how resolve the problem..

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi BEM. You seem to be missing a bracket at the end of line 2 to close the `dlply` function and create model1.

Comment: I saw two `+` in your formula (`male + + age_bin`). Is this the reason?